# How to regain the privilege to ask questions?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Appeal to regain the privilege to ask questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5147/appeal-to-regain-the-privilege-to-ask-questions)

I've had my account closed due to one bad question and a lack of input into others questions in the community (did I'm mention that I'm a NEWBIE with not much to give back yet). Is there anything I can do to be allowed to ask questions again?

Comment: The way you can give back to the community is by asking researched questions. Just because you're a newbie doesn't mean you're dumb. It just means you're new to a field. It looks like most of you're other questions all have upvotes, so you're probably only barely over the auto-ban threshold. Good luck on your edits! :)

Comment: Don't be funny!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do three things:

1. Post good answers to questions.
2. Suggest edits to other people's posts and have those edits accepted.
3. Edit your questions to make them better. Get the down-votes cancelled and questions reopened.