# Appeal to regain the privilege to ask questions

Tags: discussion, post-ban

I was denied the right to ask questions and I believe it was an unjust decision. Out of the questions I've asked I believe only one is truly subjective and about the complaint of my lack of participation in the community, well I'm a newbie. I lack the skills to really contribute much at this point and give any credible input.

On a side note, just as one gives more to their young child than they receive, so should the community expect less from new programmers before they are able to fully mature and give back to the community. This has really given me a negative impression of stackexchange and I believe that the site should really consider being more lenient with new programmers.

Comment: +1: I can't figure out how you triggered the question ban.

Comment: @JimG. You can't see deleted questions, that's why you can't figure it out. OP has asked 10 questions that were quickly closed and subsequently deleted.

Answer (score 12):

Just because you're new to programming doesn't make you an idiot. It just means you're, well... new to programming. I'm not sure why people show up on Stack Exchange and think that just because they're new to programming that somehow reading information in the FAQ or following the rules is somehow beyond them. Programming and reading a FAQ are not related skill sets... at all, and there are plenty of people new to programming who show up and ask really great, researched questions. We hold everyone to the same standard as far as the rules go, and it doesn't matter what you're skill level is.

Looking at your most recent closed question, it's off topic, and I'm not sure how to advise you to fix it since, well, it's off topic here. I'm personally better at fixing questions closed for other reasons.

There are people in this community who may be able to help you, but you'd have to post a question *asking* the community to help you fix your posts, rather than posting an indignant response asking people to roll out the red carpet for you, just because you feel like you're above the rules of our community.

People here *will* help you, if you ask, and are nice, and remain constructive, and show that you are willing to learn the norms of the community. But it involves *you* wanting to try to do what's expected, not Stack Exchange lowering the bar. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 5):

It's an automatic process.

There's nothing we (as moderators) can do.

Answer (score 4):

To elaborate on what ChrisF said, the post block is an automatic activity based on your history. This feature exists on all sites in the Stack Exchange network and is [well-discussed on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers). That post is a far better description than I can put into a post here.

The system can't distinguish between an expert and a beginner. However, regardless of your skill and knowledge level, everyone is held to the same standard when it comes to the quality of their questions and answers. The relevant things to read are our [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq), [guide on how to ask good questions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask), and the blog posts on [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) and [Real Questions Have Answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/).

I would recommend first reading those resources. Then, go through your closed or down voted questions. Not every question is salvageable easily - questions with answers are harder to save than questions that aren't answered yet.

If you need help, you can always ask very specific questions about what you can do to improve your questions. But keep in mind that not every question can be saved. Also look for any questions that you can answer - even good answers that provide new information to old questions are valuable and might help return your account to good standing.