# Banned from posting in Programmers

Tags: support, post-ban

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Appeal to regain the privilege to ask questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5147/appeal-to-regain-the-privilege-to-ask-questions)

I asked the following questions in Programmers:

1- [Determining an application's dependencies](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/155960/determining-an-applications-dependencies)

2- [Drag and drop feature for a website](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/156115/drag-and-drop-fearture-for-a-website)

Although I did not get any down-votes, still I am banned from posting more questions in Programmers. Are these questions the enough reason for this ban?

Answer (score 5):

The ban is automatic, there's little (if anything) we can do to help, you should (carefully) read and follow the advice given in [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers).

Keep in mind that deleted questions *do* factor in the post ban, and you have three of them ([10K+](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools) links):

- [Finding no. of search results in google using programming](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/162412/finding-no-of-search-results-in-google-using-programming) (-2)
- [Key concerns when developing online forums](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/155995/key-concerns-when-developing-online-forums) (-2)
- [Programming knowledge and Architecture knowledge for great products](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/155993/programming-knowledge-and-architecture-knowledge-for-great-products) (self-deleted a minute after it was posted)

The first one is the one that *probably* triggered the ban, as it's your most recent question. I can't see any way of improving any of the three, unfortunately, and undeleting them might get you more downvotes.

You should concentrate on giving *great* answers to others' questions, although the exact algorithm of the question ban is kept secret, great answers will certainly help. But please don't just rush to post answers, only answer questions that are well within your expertise and you can provide very thorough and well researched answers to.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. what is (10K+ links)? do you mean these are the total number of questions deleted so far by all the users combined?

Comment: @gpuguy It means that, since the questions are deleted, they are now only accessible to users with more than 10,000 reputation (and moderators).